# Como pegar o id de um input criado pelo jsonform?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Pessoal como faço para pegar o id de um input criado a partir de um Json com o plugin Jsonforms documentação aqui. Ele utiliza Schemas e Forms para montar o html dinamicamente, porém não estou conseguindo trabalhar com os id dos input, preciso validar os campos com o evento **blur**. Segue um exemplo de um schema criado:

```
 function getSchemaNFI(dataMap) {

 var formObject = {
   "schema": {
     "RazaoSocialDoTomador": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Razão Social do Tomador"
    }
 },

 "form": [
     {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "title": "Tomador",
        "items": [            
          "RazaoSocialDoTomador"
        ]
    }
 ],

"value": {
    "RazaoSocialDoFornecedor": getFromDataMap("RazaoSocialDoFornecedor", dataMap),
}

  "params": {
    "fieldHtmlClass": "input-text"
  }
};

return formObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seguinte, para você conseguir pegar o id de QUALQUER elemento.... basta usar a função ATTR do jquery exemplo

```
$("input").blur(function() {

console.log($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: Valeu man, já havia resolvido, pegar o id de elementos criados com este plugin não é tão simples assim, ele cria vários node lists através de json, mas, obrigado pela ajuda aí.